# When a person who is nearsighted doesn't wear corrective glasses, what happens?

Tags: vision, glasses, opthalmology

Someone wrongly tagged as duplicate my previous question.

The question is: When a person who **is nearsighted (eyeglass needs minus sign) doesn't wear corrective glasses**, does it make the situation worse?

Someone tagged this question as duplicate of [this](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/507/can-wearing-eyeglasses-cause-your-eyesight-to-degrade-further) which is opposite question.

Comment: OP here(forgot to finish registration): by worse situation I meant:  does eyesight degrade further?

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE. This is an incorrect way of rectifying what you perceive as an incorrectly closed question. If you ask a question, then find it incorrectly closed, you need to edit that question to clarify why it isn't a duplicate of the other question and ask for reopening by clicking the link below your question. My view, however, is that it is still a duplicate, even though the title of the question is opposite, because the answers contain the answer to your question too.

Comment: @ChrisRogers I can't do that I already said I logged out without registering, so I can't edit it. This is one. The answer there is not clear enough, it says if will worsen if you had lazy eye etc. But in other cases, the answer is not clear if vision will worsen if you don't use the glasses.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can wearing eyeglasses cause your eyesight to degrade further?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/507/can-wearing-eyeglasses-cause-your-eyesight-to-degrade-further)

Comment: @motosubatsu No that one doesn't it is a different question as I said, and the answer isn't entirely clear (see also comment above)

Comment: At the end of the answer it says *"Not wearing such glasses may lead to permanently defective vision"*

Comment: @ChrisRogers You have to read the 2 sentences before that too to understand to what **such** refers to. IMHO **such** glasses in your quote refers to the "kinds of glasses given to children with crossed eye....". So that answer is actually a little bit misleading the way it is written, initially I was similarly confused to  you.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the indicated question. The statement about leading to permanent defective vision refers only to the specific corrective lens for lazy/crossed eyes.